# Create Git repository with reverse domain pathing without collision

Tags: git, repository

In ActionScript (and many other languages I suspect) it is common to namespace your libraries with a unique reverse-domain path, eg: `com.zeitguys.mylibrary`, which translates to a physical directory structure of `(lib)/com/zeitguys/mylibrary`.

For the convenience of the end-user of this library, you want it to unpack and create the full path, so the repository root has the `com` directory as its only child (*or should it?*).

Suppose you are working on two different libraries, which must be able to co-exist, but they really should have separate Git repositories, since they are unrelated (other than the fact that they were created by the same author, hence the same reverse-domain stem). eg: `com.zeitguys.lib1` and `com.zeitguys.lib2`.

Now further suppose that you want to include BOTH libraries in a project, and keep them linked to their respective Git repositories. How can this be? Both repositories share a common directory structure for a few levels before branching off.

My question is about how to structure the remote repository, rather than how to checkout a subdirectory to my working copy. My perspective is thinking about the consumer of the repository and not forcing them to manually recreate the `com.zeitguys.mylibrary` structure in order to properly use the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For the convenience of the end-user of this library, you want it to unpack and create the full path, so the repository root has the com directory as its only child

1. It *can* be **task of your package-deploy tool**, not of *VCS per se* (I can imagine Git-repo in `Somedir`, which is packed to deploy into archive with path `/com/zeitguys/lib1` in it)
2. It can be task of **only deploy tool**, which will check presence and create (if needed) all intermediate parents and folder of your lib on customer's side
3. As a last resort you can use Git's submodules|subtrees, with SuperRepo (empty "container") at `/com/zeitguys/` (or just `/com`, if you use totally different namespaces), which have independent repositories in `/com/zeitguys/*` as submodules

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions. In trying to keep this simple for the repo consumers, I want to avoid deploy tools, scripts, grunt tasks, builds etc. I think this whole business of Super Repo (submodules) is probably the way to go. Do you have any examples of repositories that are set up this way?

Comment: I'm wondering whether each repo can leverage .gitignore somehow so you can still have separate repositories with the full path.

Answer (score 0):

I think my overall approach was flawed from the get-go. That is, the concept that my gitHub repository would become the directory that is included in the end-user's library path.

The fact is, that's just not going to be the case. The repository is just the repository. Inside that repository there's going to be a `src` directory and **that** directory will contain `com/zeitguys/lib1`. So the second repository would also have its own `src` directory with its `com/zeitguys/lib2`.

This insight (if you can even call it that) is quite liberating. It allows the repository to contain a bunch of other stuff that has little to do with the src code that the end user would include in their classpath / project, for example, README.md files, build scripts, an `examples` folder, test suite etc.